# Is there a way to get the address of a variable or object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Like in c++ we can get the address of a variable using the addressOf operator(&). is there a similar or any different way by which we can get the address of a variable in Javascript?

Comment: In short: no there isn't via userland code. JS doesn't expose the concept of pointers or memory addresses. If you attach an external debugger to a JS runtime this information might be available.

Comment: how can we do that?

Comment: The developer tools of web browsers contain detailed memory analytics functionality (useful for diagnosing memory leaks etc).